vim-tmux-navigator won't work inside nvim when used with tmux
Steps to reproduce my problem:

Create a tmux session
Open two tmux splits, first one horizontal and inside this one vertical
In the left split, open nvim and create an horizontal split.
So now, I'm in the right split of Neovim. If I do Ctrl + H, instead of arriving in Neovim's left pane, I loop and arrive in tmux bottom right pane. So basically Neovim's left tab becomes unaccessible by control as soon as I create a split in Neovim.

Here's my config
~/.config/nvim/lua/theo/plugins/init.lua
return {
  "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim", -- lua functions that many plugins use
  "christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator", -- tmux & split window navigation
}

~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix

unbind %
bind | split-window -h

unbind '"'
bind - split-window -v

unbind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

bind -r j resize-pane -D 5
bind -r k resize-pane -U 5
bind -r l resize-pane -R 5
bind -r h resize-pane -L 5

bind -r m resize-pane -Z

set -g mouse on

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection # start selecting text with "v"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection # copy text with "y"

unbind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane # don't exit copy mode after dragging with mouse

# tpm plugin
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'

# list of tmux plugins
set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator' # for navigating panes and vim/nvim with Ctrl-hjkl
set -g @plugin 'jimeh/tmux-themepack' # to configure tmux theme
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect' # persist tmux sessions after computer restart
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum' # automatically saves sessions for you every 15 minutes

set -g @themepack 'powerline/default/cyan' # use this theme for tmux

set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on' # allow tmux-ressurect to capture pane contents
set -g @continuum-restore 'on' # enable tmux-continuum functionality

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.config/tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'

